# Excel VBA to loop and find specific range and concatenate 2 cell values and delete empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to identify a specific range in column-A and concatenate two cells within the specific range and delete the empty cell. I have been successful in putting a code together and it does the job very well. But, I don't know how to loop it to identify next range. Any help would be appreciated.

As per below image and code, First, I am finding and selecting a range between two (MCS) in column-A with a condition that, if the rows are more than 8 between two MCS. Then I am concatenating first 2 cells immediately after MCS and delete the empty row.

The below code works well for first range but I am unable to loop to identify next range from row 22 to 32 and perform concatenations.

I dont know how to loop in column-A and select ranges and concatenate. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

[image]

```
Sub MergeStem()
    Dim findMCS1 As Long
    Dim findMCS2 As Long
    Dim myCount As Integer
    Dim myStems As Long
    Dim mySelect As Range
    Dim c As Range

    findMCS1 = Range("A:A").Find("MCS", Range("A1")).Row
    findMCS2 = Range("A:A").Find("MCS", Range("A" & findMCS1)).Row

    myCount = Range("A" & findMCS1 + 1 & ":A" & findMCS2 - 1).Cells.Count
    Range("B1").Value = myCount
    MsgBox "Number of rows =" & myCount

    Set mySelect = Selection

    If myCount > 8 Then
        myStems = Range("A" & findMCS1 + 2 & ":A" & findMCS2 - 9).Select

        Set mySelect = Selection

        For Each c In mySelect.Cells
            If firstcell = "" Then firstcell = c.Address(bRow, bCol)
            sArgs = sArgs + c.Text + " "

            c.Value = ""
        Next
        Range(firstcell).Value = sArgs
    End If

    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this? Ordinarily, `Find` would be the way to go but because you are deleting rows it's hard to keep track of which cells you've found.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long, n1 As Long, n2 As Long

With Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For r = .Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(r).Value = "MCS" Then
            If n1 = 0 Then
                n1 = .Cells(r).Row
            Else
                n2 = .Cells(r).Row
            End If
            If n1 > 0 And n2 > 0 Then
                If n1 - n2 > 9 Then
                    .Cells(r + 1).Value = .Cells(r + 1).Value & .Cells(r + 2).Value
                    '.Cells(r + 2).EntireRow.Delete
                    'Call procedure to delete row 
                End If
                n1 = n2
                n2 = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR, it is working fine for range above 8. But it is also concatenating and deleting a row if the range = 8.

Comment: Is it possible to concatenate and leave the blank row without deleting and call another macro to delete empty cells.

Comment: (1) Try changing ">8" to ">9" (2) Yes.

Comment: Glad we got there.